# Adding title + buttons to UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm getting crazy to solve this problem.

I've the following code in my `AppDelegate.m` 
Basically a navigation controller + tab bar that link to 2 tableviewcontroller

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    ElencoSpese *elenco=[[ElencoSpese alloc] init];
    elenco.tabBarItem.title=@"Prova 123";

    ElencoSpese *elenco2=[[ElencoSpese alloc] init];
    elenco2.tabBarItem.title=@"Prova 222";

    UITabBarController *tabMenu = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabMenu.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:elenco, elenco2, nil];


    UINavigationController *navig=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabMenu];
    self.window.rootViewController=navig;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

`ElencoSpese` is a `TableViewController` and it works ok. I want to add `"title"` to this window and "+" and `"Edit"` button on top of the `NavigationBar`....

I've tried to uncomment the following in the loadview method of the tableviewcontroller: no result

```
// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

I've alsto tried in the appdelegate to set title....nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Do Like this..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    ElencoSpese *elenco=[[ElencoSpese alloc] init];
    elenco.tabBarItem.title=@"Prova 123";

    ElencoSpese *elenco2=[[ElencoSpese alloc] init];
    elenco2.tabBarItem.title=@"Prova 222";
    UINavigationController *navig=[[UINavigationController alloc]     initWithRootViewController:elenco];
UINavigationController *navig1 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:elenco2];

    UITabBarController *tabMenu = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabMenu.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navig, navig1, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController=tabMenu;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Then each **TableViewController  -viewDidLoad** add like this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.title = @"Calculator"; 
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(yourSelectorMethod)];

    UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(yourSelectorMethod1)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The viewcontroller is embedded in a tabbar-controller, which is pushed in a navigationcontroller. So you should access the navigationitem like so:

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Comment: No way....I've added (with no results...): self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController.navigationItem.title=@"ciao";
    self.window.rootViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.window.rootViewController.editButtonItem; Thanks fot he help

Answer (score 0):

the title for the window can be given as below

after the line in your code

```
self.window.rootViewController=navig;
```

just add

```
self.tabbarController.navigationItem.title = @"YOUR TITLE";
```

this will help you to give title

Comment: No way....I've added (with no results...): self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController.navigationItem.title=@"ciao";
    self.window.rootViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.window.rootViewController.editButtonItem; Thanks for the support